# Property in dependency defined by custom plugin

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

We have a custom plugin that runs during the `initialize` phase of our Maven build, and sets certain properties to the project. We also have a dependency, whose version relies on those properties. Our build is failing because the dependency version is invalid, because the project attempts to resolve the dependency before the plugin runs. Is there any way around this? Potential solutions (that I don't know how to implement):

1. Somehow allow the plugin to run before the project really even kicks off/attempts to resolve dependencies
2. delay the dependency resolution until later in the lifecycle

Are either of these possible?

Edit: Following a couple questions on context I'll provide some.

For a couple of different reasons, maintaining versions in a large parent (aggregator) pom file was becoming a big problem for us, so it actually started to make sense for us to define them in an external service. The plugin reads in the current versions off of the service, and sets them to properties. A couple of these properties would be used as dependency versions.

Anticipating the comments to be -> "you should just go back to using the large aggregator", we can.... but it is definitely as a last resort.

Edit 2: relevant part of POM per request:

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.myCompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>myDep</artifactId>
    <version>${myDep.major.version}.${myDep.minor.version}</version>
    <type>ear</type>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Traditionally `myDep.major.version` and `myDep.minor.version` we're defined in our parent `pom.xml,` but now we want to move them to the service we're using.

Comment: How is the dependency relying on the properties you set during `initialize`? Adding the relevant parts of your POM to your question would be helpful.

Comment: Why are you settings properties for dependencies? And using a plugin for that? You can't solve that with a plugin....The only way to do that is using an extension...but the question is which kind of problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @GeroldBroser I don't think the POM is particularly helpful, but I have provided additional context if that helps

Comment: @pasquers Does this translate to "I don't have a POM, yet"? :)

Comment: Haha no I promise! I'll post it for completion's sake but I don't think itll help a ton lol

Comment: I think the dependency resolution happening prior to plugin execution is not the only issue. According to the thread [Variables interpolation: dynamic in Maven 2, static in Maven 3 ?](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Variables-interpolation-dynamic-in-Maven-2-static-in-Maven-3-td3360336.html) also variable interpolation happens before plugin execution, so your `initialize` plugin wouldn't set anything. – If you have a really big parent/aggregator (How big is big here?) is it possible to benefit from Maven's hierarchical configuration inheritance and separate declarations? That's what I do.